# Selecting images in Javascript using

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning to use Javascript and HTML, so I need some guidance. I want to make a Web Page using a function, loop, and event listener. I want my page to show eight states affected by flooding and each state to be clickable. With one state being the correct state to click on. If someone could help me get started, I would be very thankful!

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended for questions about code that already exists (i.e., you have a specific problem with specific code and you do not understand why it is not working). However, it is not intended to provide tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html add eight respective containers say div with proper unique Id. Use the event click. On click call a function passing the div id. 
In JavaScript, map each Id to a state and pass the relevant information back to html.

Note: the container can be any html component.